# Telegram linktext that executes a command?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I would like to send a message with my telegram bot that has a clickable text (link). This is something that you can do with HTML. 
However, this link should not open a website but rather send a command to my bot (same way as when simply sending a command with the bot like /start).

My idea was

```
<a href="/help"> Display help </a>
```

but this doesn't produce a clickable link

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. `<a href= >` expects a Url to follow.

The easiest way would be to send a message like "Press /help for more."

`/help` will turn into a "clickable link" and a command is send to the bot when pressed.

[image]